# Mongoose find by value in array of key value pairs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find a document from the structure

```
    "brandcredits": [
        {
            "brand_id": "5586da128a60ebcb7abeb732",
            "brand_credits": 123,
            "_id": "558ce2af106319b412e48b6c"
        },
        {
            "brand_id": "5586da238a60ebcb7abeb733",
            "brand_credits": 500,
            "_id": "558ce2af106319b412e48b6b"
        },
        {
            "brand_id": "558b382e7881f424154d6c27",
            "brand_credits": 500,
            "_id": "558ce2af106319b412e48b6a"
        },
        {
            "brand_id": "558b38467881f424154d6c28",
            "brand_credits": 500,
            "_id": "558ce2af106319b412e48b69"
        },
        {
            "brand_id": "558b38687881f424154d6c29",
            "brand_credits": 245,
            "_id": "558ce2af106319b412e48b68"
        }
    ]
```

My mongoose query is

```
BrandInfo.find({'_id':{$in: user[0].brandcredits.brand_id}},function(err,active){
           console.log(active);
});
```

Which returns undefined

I need to query a schema with the array of brand_id.
How do I do that?
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is searching for `_id` in `user[0].brandcredits.brand_id` which doesn't work, or even make sense because `user[0].brandcredits.brand_id` itself is just another ObjectID.

What you need to be searching for is: **`brand_id`** ***in*** **`user[0].brandcredits`**

So try this:

```
BrandInfo.find( { 'brand_id': {$in: user[0].brandcredits} } , function(err, active){
    console.log(active);
});
```